# Как правильно подключить шаблон вида для блока/модуля (Drupal 8)?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal8

Создал простой модуль, далее вывел его в регион - все работает.

А если информации выводимой через модуль будет много, то ее нужно как-то оформить, как правильно подключить шаблон (вьюху) вывода информации в модуле?

Пример модуля:

```
class BlockTest extends BlockBase {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function build() {
                return array(
                    '#markup' => $this->t('Hello, World 123 !'),
                );
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте здесь внизу [Create a custom block](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-block)
Там пишет что не выйдет просто создать шаблон блока по примеру

```
block--CUSTOM_BLOCK_NAME.html.twig
```

Вам нужно изменить свой код следуюющим образом

```
public function build() {
  return array(
    '#theme' => 'block_custom_test',   
    '#markup' => $this->t('Hello, World 123 !'),
  );
}
```

Потом использовать следующий хук

```
function YOUR_MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'block_custom_test' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'block--custom-test',
      'base hook' => 'block'
    )
  );
}
```

После можете создать шаблон и использовать его

```
block--custom-test.html.twig
```